# Sometimes onPostExecute(Byte val) not getting called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using async task with latest OS Oreo, my issue is onPostExecute() called every time but once in a while it is not getting called. I am wondering which use case is not allowing to get it called.

More details on the task I am doing:-

I am trying to open Bluetooth socket inside doInBackground then return 0 from this method.

```
 mBTConnectTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Byte>() {         
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        LogConfig.logd(TAG,"BTConnectTask : onPreExecute show progressBar");
                }

   @Override
   protected Byte doInBackground(Void... params) {
       LogConfig.logd(TAG, "Inside startBluetoothProcess");
       byte val = BTinit(context);
       if (val == 0) {
           if (BTconnect()) {
               return ErrorStatus.DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED;
          }
       } else {
              return val;
         }
         return 0;
    }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Byte val) {
      LogConfig.logd(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
      }

  };

 mBTConnectTask.execute();
```

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: maybe it is showing any exception in your doInBackground method. add try catch block in doInBackground and test it

Comment: Your code is underspecified, you should provide more context. What does BTConnect do? Is this the server socket or the client socket? What kind of socket are you going to open?